# Find ranges in array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I've been trying to find the optimal solution to the following (interesting?) problem that came up at work: Eventually I settled for a good enough solution but I'd like to know if there's a better one.

Let a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>n</sub> be an array of strings.

Let s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>k</sub> be an unordered list of strings, all of them also members of the array.

The task is to find the minimum set of index ranges eleements of `s` cover in `a`.

So for example if a = [ "x", "y", "a", "f", "c" ] and s = { "c","y","f" }, the answer would be (1;1), (3;4), assuming that the array is indexed from zero.

`a` is typically fairly large (hundreds of thousands of elements), while `s` is relatively small, typically length(s) < log(length(a)).

So the question is: can you find a time-efficient algorithm for this problem? (Space efficiency is not a concern within reasonable limits.)

Just a quick but important update: I need to perform this operation with different `s` values but the same `a` a lot. So precomputing stuff based on `a` is allowed, indeed it is the only way.

Comment: You mean (S0:A4),(S1:A1),(S2:F4)?

Comment: No, I mean that "c" and "f" are consecutive in `a`, and they span a range between indices 3-4, "y" stands alone, so it's just a range of 1-1.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an important part of the algorithm that the members of "a" aren't necessarily distinct? (Otherwise you just look up the positions of each string in a map, sort them, and coalesce sequential ones).

Comment: @Chris Nash No, they are distinct, so this approach works. It just didn't feel optimal somehow. But maybe I have to concede that it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a hash table `H(a)` to map from element to index: `a`<sub>x</sub>`->x` in `O(n)` time and space. Then look up each s<sub>y</sub> in `H(a)` (in `O(1)` time on average for a total of `O(k)` for `s`) and keep track of the ranges. For that you can use an array of `pair(min_index, max_index)` sorted by `min_index` and do a binary search to either locate the range or where you should insert the new 1 element range.
So overall, the solution above would take `O( n + k + k * log( nb_ranges ) )` time and `O( n + nb_ranges )` space.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, written in python:

```
def flattened(indexes):
    s, rest = indexes[0], indexes[1:]
    result = (s, s)
    for e in rest:
        if e == result[1] + 1:
            result = (result[0], e)
        else:
            yield result
            result = (e, e)
    yield result

a = ["x", "y", "a", "f", "c"]
s = ["c", "y", "f"]

# Create lookup table of ai to index in a
src_indexes = dict((key, i) for i, key in enumerate(a))

# Create sorted list of all indexes into a
raw_dst_indexes = sorted(src_indexes[key] for key in s)

# Convert sorted list of indexes into an array of ranges
dst_indexes = [r for r in flattened(raw_dst_indexes)]

print dst_indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can throw the elements of S into a set or hashtable, anything with near O(1) to check for membership.  Then just do a linear scan on A, with a flag to determine if you are currently covering elements in S, and the start position of that cover.  Should be O(n + k).

Comment: Well, this was my original idea and it proved to be kinda slow.